# If a remote Sub-Antarctic research base goes dark/loses communication, who would be sent to investigate?

Tags: research, investigation, polar

The story takes place on a research station located on a remote Subantarctic island. It's an amalgamation of various existing islands like the Kerguelen islands, Macquarie island and South Georgia Island, which are overseas territories of France, UK and Australia respectively. Let's say the island in my story is on a British overseas territory, and is managed by the British Antarctic Survey. All of a sudden, there hasn't been any communication from the base for weeks - they've gone completely dark. There's a supply ship that goes to the island a few times a year (based on the real-life [*Marion Dufresne*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marion_Dufresne_(1994)) vessel that resupplies Kerguelen and Crozet islands), and that one hasn't returned from its last supply run. There were 15ish people on the base and they haven't been heard from at all.

In a situation such as this, what would be the protocol? Who would take on the accountability to try and figure out what happened on the base? Who would be sent to investigate? Would it be military, or a group of researchers/scientists? Or would they just send a helicopter to do a landing? A drone flyover? What are we planning here?

Answer (score 6):

I believe that this would be sufficiently one-of-a-kind that people would make it up as they go.

- After the initial failure to answer (satlink) phones, the support organization might *report* this to their government and *inquire* if the government has any information.
- In parallel, they may be looking for [commercial imagery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_imagery) from a [sun-synchronous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun-synchronous_orbit) (i.e. polar-orbit) recon sat. Any visible results (burned-out buildings, SOS trampled in the snow, ...) would turn the mystery into an emergency.
- As long as it is merely a communications failure, they could look for signs of routine activity (possibly even people outside), that would reduce the panic level.
- If the supply ship had an [AIS transponder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_identification_system) and that goes dark, there is a last known position. Is that at the island, and can the ship be found in the sat images?
- A missing ship constitutes an emergency at sea, where military ships and aircraft as well as civilian ships would be expected to respond, to the best of their ability. Compare the [Sydney to Hobart race](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1998_Sydney_to_Hobart_Yacht_Race) in 1998.